# How to make an existing website themeable?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, themes

I'm very new to this sort of thing, and I'm working on an existing production website. I've never styled a site from scratch, but what I'm trying to do is add some kind of functionality that allows users to customize their own themes, which will then be applied to the site.

I apologize for the question being so bare, but what I'm looking for are different methods to make an existing web application themeable. I'm not entirely sure how to get more specific than that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently checked just this thing up and you can make it themeable with some jQuery. Go to http://jqueryui.com/slider/ and browse through the examples on the side. It's some sliders you can use for example opacity or how many columns that should be used. Also a colorpicker isn't to bad (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp). But to do all this stuff you will need to learn some languages like HTML, CSS, JS, PHP, jQuery etc etc. It all can be very advanced to a user that never used the languages before.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an advanced topic to discuss and the complexity of it may depend on you wen design and what parts of it are you trying to keep dynamically themed. In general practice, people choose header, footer, background fore colors as dynamic and create separate style sheets for them, you then let the user choose theme from a control and swap the style sheets. The basic wireframe template styles generally go in a common style sheet. You could also make your page a bit dynamic by letting user choose say 2 colum layout or 3 col layout. This is really a go crazy topic and perhaps there is quite a lot which could be done.